# Oracle for an inverse function

Tags: complexity-theory, oracle-machines

A. Let $F$ be a monotonically increasing real function from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$. Given an oracle to $F$ and a number $y$, is there a way to calculate the inverse function $F^{-1}(y)$ in a finite number of calls to the oracle?

I think the answer is no, because of a simple counting argument: there are uncountably many possible answers, and with a finite number of calls we can get only countably many answers. Is this correct?

B. Let $F, G$ be two functions as above, and let $H$ be their average: $H(x)=[F(x)+G(x)]/2$. Given an oracle to $F^{-1}$ and an oracle to $G^{-1}$ and a number $y$, is there a way to calculate $H^{-1}(y)$ in a finite number of calls?

I think the answer is no, but how can I formalize the counting argument?

Is this possible to reduce to this problem from problem A? Or from another problem which provably cannot be solved in finite time?

NOTE: It can be argued that any function on reals is inherently infinite because even the output of a real number might take infinite time. So for this question, assume that we have a computer that can input, output and do arithmetics on real numbers in constant time per operation.

<sup>[similar question was posted in math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231027/oracle-for-the-inverse-function), no answers yet.</sup>

Comment: For (A) I concur with your reason, and it seems like a straightforward adversary argument, where you make any series of queries, and the adversary can pick a number that satisifies all the queries but is not the inverse. I think a similar argument could be constructed for (B). I'll have a go when I don't have to go catch a train ;) (or Yuval will get there first ;) anyway).

Comment: Since you are defining $F^{-1}$, you must assume $F$ is *strictly*
monotonically increasing, so as to be bijective (since *onto*). - - -
- - The problem with using the traditional real in your question is
not just that it takes infinite time to output, but more radically
that it cannot be output by any Turing Machine. Is there a consistent
theory about computability and algorithms over the traditional uncountable reals? Can you give
a reference?

Comment: @babou I am not aware of a theory about computability in reals. But what's wrong with just assuming that we have a computer with registers that can hold real numbers?

Comment: Because everything we know about computation is based on ultimate
finiteness of definitions. In a real number, you can encode infinite
information. So you can probably do otherwise infinite computations in
one step. I am not expert enough to have a definite opinion without
more work, but there is a distinct possibility that using reals that
way makes anything computable. This is why I am asking whether there
is a consistent theory, one in which some things are true and some
others are false. You cannot take that for granted. What are your
axioms.

Comment: I assume you are aware that your problem A is solvable trivially for
integers, and in finite unbounded time for rationals. For computable
reals, it is solvable as the digits of $F^{-1}(y)$ can be enumerated,
but this takes of course infinite time, so that the time bound is just
infinite countable time (though this cannot be done by enumerating the
computable reals). I cannot go further to traditional reals
because I have no theory for doing that that I know to be consistent.
I can write that down for an answer if you wish.

Comment: @babou I just found this question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29567/are-there-established-complexity-classes-with-real-numbers

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this question I had forgotten. What it
actually means is not too clear. It is not even clear they mean
uncountable reals. I am asking there, and I was already
investigating some related issues. By the way, your two problems A an
B are equivalent, with some very limited assumptions.

Comment: @babou can you elaborate on the equivalence of the two problems? This is interesting.

Comment: Sorry. I wrote too fast. All I have is reduction of B to A.

Comment: @babou A reduction of B to A is also interesting. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you mean reduction of B to A is already an answer for you, I can give that as answer. I may be wrong, but I think A does not reduce to B. Then direct answer to either question A or B is not something I understand as I do not understand your view of reals, or the reference you give.

Comment: Regarding the use of reals, maybe you could wonder whether you can get
a given approximation in finite time. This should be possible, I
conjecture. The issue though might be whether you can do that
uniformly, i.e. whether you can have the same upperbound on the time
needed for a given approximation everywhere on the interval. I suspect
that this depends on differential properties of the function $F$ (not
meaning to imply that it has to be derivable). But I am not sure what you are trying to get at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am skipping the first question, question A, as it is not clear to me
how it can make sense formally, since I am not familiar with the
formalizations the OP mentions in a comment: [Are there established complexity classes with real numbers?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29567/are-there-established-complexity-classes-with-real-numbers)

I am only adressing the relation between question A and question B,
proving that question B can be reduced to question A, which the OP considers of interest in itself. And since we are supposed to deal with only one question at a time, this follows the local rules. **:)**

### Question B reduces to question A : B ≤ A

First I will rephrase both questions, so as to add a missing
hypothesis (bijectivity of the function, though existence of an
inverse implies it), and also to use notations that will make the proof
easier to state.

**Question A**: Let $F$ be a bijective, monotonically increasing real
function from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$. Given an oracle to compute $F$ on
any input and a number $y\in[0,1]$, is there a way to calculate the
inverse function $F^{-1}(y)$ in a finite number of calls to the $F$
oracle?

**Question B**: Let $H, K$ be two functions like $F$ above, and let $G$ be
their average: $G(x)=[H(x)+K(x)]/2$. Given an oracle to compute
$H^{-1}$ and an oracle to compute $K^{-1}$ and a number $y\in[0,1]$,
is there a way to calculate $G^{-1}(y)$ in a finite number of calls to
the $H$ and $K$ oracles.?

Note: all functions considered are bijective monotonic, but for
readability we leave implicit the related arguments, though they do matter in some of the inferences below.

The idea of the proof is that, if $x=G^{-1}(y)$ is a solution to
problem B, then there are two numbers $h,k\in[0,1]$ such that

1. $y=(h+k)/2$, and
2. $h=H(x)$, and $k=K(x)$ for some $x\in [0,1]$

We try to resolve the problem by defining a variable $u\in[0,1]$, so
that $h$ and $k$ are computed from $u$ to take all possible values
while $u$ varies from $0$ to $1$.

From $y=(h+k)/2$ we get $h+k=2y$. So we define: $h_u=2yu$ and
$k_u=2y(1-u)$.
This ensures that $y=(h_u+k_u)/2$, but will let $h_u$ or $k_u$ become greater than $1$ when $y$ is greater than $1/2$.

So, we must actually consider two somewhat similar cases, depending on the value of $y$, after noting that $h_u$ and $k_u$ are both monotonically increasing functions of $u$.

**case 1**: $y\leq 1/2$

What we want is to find $h$ and $k$ such that $h=H(x)$ and $k=K(x)$
for some value $x$.

We define the function
$D(u)=H^{-1}(h_u)-K^{-1}(k_u)=H^{-1}(2yu)-K^{-1}(2y(1-u))$
Note that $H^{-1}(0)=K^{-1}(0)=0$.
Hence $D(0)=H^{-1}(0)-K^{-1}(2y)=-K^{-1}(2y)$,
and $D(1)=H^{-1}(2y)-K^{-1}(0)=H^{-1}(2y)$.

So the function $D(u)$ is increasing onto $[-K^{-1}(2y),H^{-1}(2y)]$,
and the solution to finding the value of $u$ that corresponds to the
right values of $h$ and $k$ is given by the equation $D(u)=0$.

However, we intend to resolve it using an algorithm to solve
question A, so we must normalize the interval to make it $[0,1]$.

For that we define
$F(u)=\frac{D(u)+K^{-1}(2y)}{H^{-1}(2y)+K^{-1}(2y)}$
The function $F$ satisfies the conditions of question A,
and we remark that $D(u)=0$ iff
$F(u)=\frac{K^{-1}(2y)}{H^{-1}(2y)+K^{-1}(2y)}$.
So we have to compute
$u_0=F^{-1}(\frac{K^{-1}(2y)}{H^{-1}(2y)+K^{-1}(2y)})$, which can be
done using the algorithm answering question A.
Then $G^{-1}(y)=H^{-1}(2yu_0)$, or to summarize in one formula:

$$G^{-1}(y)=H^{-1}(2yF^{-1}(\frac{K^{-1}(2y)}{H^{-1}(2y)+K^{-1}(2y)}))$$

Each computation of $F(u)$ uses only a finite (small) number of calls to the
oracles for $H^{-1}$ and $K^{-1}$. Thus a solution to question B can
be computed with a finite number of oracle calls if that is the case
for problem A.

**case 2**: $y>1/2$

This case is a bit more complicated, as different bounds must be found
for varying $u$ so that $h$ and $k$ do not get greater than $1$, since
the functions $H$ and $K$ are defined only onto $[0,1]$.

Since $y=(h_u+k_u)/2$, we have $h_u=2y-k_u$. Thus, $k_u\leq 1$ implies
$h_u\geq 2y-1$.

The same reasonning holds, exchanging $h$ and $k$, so that we have
$h_u,k_u\in [2y-1, 1]$. Since $u=h_u/(2y)$, we have $u\in[u_0,u_1]$
with $u_0=1-1/(2y)$ and $u_1=1/(2y)$.

In order to have a variable $v$ varying in $[0,1]$, we normalize by
defining $v=(u-u_0)/(u_1-u_0)$. But
$u_1-u_0=1/(2y)-(1-1/(2y))=(1-y)/y$
which gives $v=(u-u_0)y/(1-y)$.
Hence, with $u=v(1-y)/y+u_0$, $u$ is
a function of $v$ monotonically increasing onto $[u_0,u_1]$ when
$v\in[0,1]$.

Thus, considering $h$ and $k$ as functions of $v$ we have
$h_v=2y(v(1-y)/y+u_0)$ and $k_v=2y(1-(v(1-y)/y+u_0))$, with $u_0=1-1/(2y)$

Simplifying we get $h_v=2y-1+2v(1-y)$ and $k_v=1-2v(1-y)$, for $v\in[0,1]$

From here on the reasonning is the same as for the first case, since monotonically increasing functions are closed under composition, the variable being $v$ rather than $u$, considering the function:
$D(v)=H^{-1}(h_v)-K^{-1}(k_v)=H^{-1}(2y-1+2v(1-y))-K^{-1}(1-2v(1-y))$

I hope that there is no error in symbol manipulations, but the line of reasonning should not be affected if that were the case.

The proof can be simplified by using a lemma that generalizes the question A, which is here a hypothesis, to any strictly increasing function from any closed interval to any other closed interval.