# Soft Question: Looking for resources on computation over reals

Tags: complexity-theory, data-structures, mathematical-foundations

As the title suggests, I want to take a look at resources (books, lectures or papers) that are available (free or paid) on computation over reals.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are several different notions of computation over the real, see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29567/are-there-established-complexity-classes-with-real-numbers). Which are you interested in?

Comment: What a brilliant thread that is! I havent quite gone through all of the papers mentioned there though, but I am interested in the Computability of Measure Spaces or Computable Measure Spaces and Integration theory (if there exists such a thing).

Comment: Also I would like to know if there are other papers like this one here : http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar_url?url=https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00425556/file/paper.pdf&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm2LtAL3bbUmNzcnQV86qJjCxwSaDg&nossl=1&oi=scholarr&ved=0ahUKEwjk79_exvrXAhUgTo8KHavDASsQgAMIJygCMAA

Comment: The usual ways to answer this question are: (1) look at papers cited by the paper; (2) look at papers citing the paper; (3) find other papers by the same authors; (4) find other papers using similar terminology. You don't need me for that.